# Multiple inclusion of ui-sref AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I encounter a minor problem with AngularJS ui-sref and Html.

I would like to create a Div which contains multiple buttons. Each button has to redirect to a specific page, but if I click in the main Div, not on a button, I would like to move to another page.

Here is my code example :

```
<div id="main" ui-sref="main_page">
    <button id="button1" ui-sref="page1">Page 1</button>
    <button id="button2" ui-sref="page2">Page 2</button>
    <button id="button3" ui-sref="page3">Page 3</button>
    <button id="button4" ui-sref="page4">Page 4</button>
</div>
```

BUT, where ever I click, it redirects me to the "main_page".

Do you have any idea to solve it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An an `ng-click` event to your `div` container instead of `ui-sref`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Next in your controller at your method call `$state.go(state);`.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Here is an example:

```
<div id="main" ng-click="redirect()">
    <button id="button1" ui-sref="page1">Page 1</button>
    <button id="button2" ui-sref="page2">Page 2</button>
    <button id="button3" ui-sref="page3">Page 3</button>
    <button id="button4" ui-sref="page4">Page 4</button>
</div>
```

And example controller:

angular
        .module('App')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

```
MainController.$inject = [
    '$scope',
    '$state'
];

function MainController($scope, AccessService, Overlay) {
    $scope.redirect = function(){
        $state.go('newPage');
    }
}
```

You can also check if the click element is not a button. I haven't tested this so it is possible that when you bound `ngClick` to your `div` container then also on button click inside this containers it will call `redirect` method.

Example check:

```
$scope.redirect = function(event) {
   if(event.target.className !== 'button')
       $state.go('newPage');
}
```

You need to add class to your buttons:

```
<div id="main" ng-click="redirect($event)">
    <button class="button" id="button1" ui-sref="page1">Page 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="button2" ui-sref="page2">Page 2</button>
    <button class="button" id="button3" ui-sref="page3">Page 3</button>
    <button class="button" id="button4" ui-sref="page4">Page 4</button>
</div>
```

Remember to pass `$event` to the `redirect` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the use `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` to stop the event propagation in the nested events, as described by angular-ui  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-prevent-nested-ui-sref-objects-from-all-firingtriggering.

Your code will then look like the following:

```
<div id="main" ui-sref="main_page">
    <button id="button1" ui-sref="page1" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Page 1</button>
    <button id="button2" ui-sref="page2" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Page 2</button>
    <button id="button3" ui-sref="page3" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Page 3</button>
    <button id="button4" ui-sref="page4" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Page 4</button>
</div>
```